# Java read each lines of numbers from text file using Scanner class, finding max value

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Hello I'm a java beginner and I'm working on an assignment. I need to read in numbers from text file, then print out message if they are invalid

1st number (Int) needs to be 0~99999

2nd number (Int) needs to be 0~5

3rd number (double) needs to be 0~100.00

```
the txt file looks like this, the numbers represent student ID, extra credit, grade
51673 0 98.85 
19438 5 95.00 
00483 3 73.16
```

and here is what I have so far...
any hint is greatly appericiated

```
public static void validateDate(File inputFile) 
        x = new Scanner(new File("xxx.txt");
        while(x.hasNext())!= null) {    
        int a = x.next();
        int b = x.next();
        double c = x.next();
)


if (a < 0 || a > 99999){ 
System.out.print("Ignoring student with invalid ID number " + a);
}
if ( b < 0 || b > 5){ 
System.out.println("Ignoring student " + a + " with invalid extra credit" + b);
}
if ( c < 0 || c > 100){
System.out.println("Ignoring student " + a + " with invalid grade " + c);
}
```

I also need to write another method to find max value of all the 3rd numbers, any suggestions?

Comment: looking at your method name `validateDate()`, are the numbers represent date?

Comment: `Scanner#next` returns a `String`. Look in the javadoc of `Scanner` class and check which method returns `int` or `double` data.

Comment: There are a lot of mistakes in the code. You want more than just a hint.

Comment: @Immer Allein: the numbers represent student ID, extra credit, grade.

Comment: Think about the scope of the variables `a` `b` and `c`.  Think about what `while` does

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation of [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). Check what functions return int and double and use them instead of **next();**. Also for maximum value simply take another variable **max=0.0;** and check if every c is greater than that. If yes then assign **max** with the value of **c**.

Please Note: I could have spoiled by spoonfeeding you but I chose giving hints because you'll *learn* that way.

Comment: @user3604043 Please accept this as the answer if it resolved your issue. :)